# scala regex match up to a specific string but whole string if the specific word doesn't exist

Tags: regex, scala

I have a question about scala regex

The thing I need to do is given a string, I need to find a sub-string up to a specific word given. For example, my regular expression looks like following

```
val x= "(?s)^(.*)(?=(foo|bar)".r
```

Then given a string, I need to find the longest sub-string until before foo or bar. This works perfectly but I would like to get the whole string if the string does not contain foo or bar at all.

Right now if I do

```
x.findAllIn("hello nice to meet you").toArray
```

it gives me an empty string but I would like to get
`"hello nice to meet you"` when I do that.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an end-of-string assertion to the alternative:

```
(?s)^(.*?)(?=(foo|bar|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: This just always returns the whole string. You have to make the quantifier reluctant as well: `(?s)^(.*?)(?=(foo|bar|$))`

Comment: sure, you're right, correcting